# Retrieve an image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how can i retreive an image in asp.net called "dddd" from a file system and show it on the web page?

Comment: Note that it helps to provide more information in order to give a good answer.  For example, where is the file located in relation to your web app?

Comment: I do have an image in a folder in my server. I want to access this image and view it on my web page

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
           ImageUrl="dddd.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is located in your web app, then just use the ImageUrl property.  @Bala R provided a good example.

If the file is located outside of the path of your web app then you will need to create a virtual directory that points to that location.

If you are talking about a file that is on the clients computer, then you can't do this at all.

Comment: I do have an image in a folder in my server. I want to access this image and view it on my web page.

Comment: in that case try setting ImageUrl="imageFolder/dddd.png" for Image control.

Comment: @hhh: Bala has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/dddd.png" />
```

~/ImageLocationFolder/Image

Regards