# view image in a non-Project folder

Tags: asp.net

I upload an image to my server in a folder Called Updates. Than I'm trying to view this pic by using the following:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="C:/Uploads/ec.jpg" />
```

Basically ec.jpg is in a folder called Uploads which is in C:. When I run my web app the pic doesn't show.

Now if I put the image in my actual Project file and than I try viewing it, it shows just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retreive an image in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466795/retreive-an-image-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

OK, so my answer above is valid if you just want to point to the image via ImageUrl. You can use a handler to access the image outside of your app path though. This is an example handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    HttpResponse r = context.Response;
        r.ContentType = "image/png";

    string file = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
    r.WriteFile(file);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a a Generic Handler, use the above code. If you created it with the file name of Image.ashx in the root of you application you would then:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image.ashx?file=C:/Uploads/ec.jpg"/>
```

***This Is NOT Production Quality Code***
as there are no safeguards and this handler would return any file from the hard disk!

Answer (score 0):

ImageUrl is a relative or absolute URL to your image. Your image *must* be within the web application's hierarchy or it won't be accessible by your application

Comment: IS their a way to view it if it wasn't in my web app?

Comment: Yes, look into web handlers. you need the handler to open the image and pass the data back to the browser.... much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

@justin808 is Right..

Add ImageFolder on your Solution.

And then use

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImageFolder/ec.jpg"/>
```

By simply draging your image on your designer.

Regards