# access images outside the web path

Tags: asp.net

How can i display images that are saved outside the the WebSite folder. Any example would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: where are your images? Give an example of what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retreive an image in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466795/retreive-an-image-in-asp-net)

Comment: If you have further details regarding your original question, the best thing to do is update the original question.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you could write a handler that would know the location of your files then use the `Response.WriteFile` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx to get the file and write it to the output stream.

You would need to set the content type first so the browser knows what you're doing.

Similar to what is being done in this example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-writefile

Comment: If the file is outside of the website root path then this method won't work.

Comment: @Chris Lively, tested that method right now and it works fine for me.

Comment: @x2: If you ran it on your localhost, then yeah it would work. However, if it's deployed to a server then the user the app pool is running under would have to have rights to the relevant directory. This is not a normal configuration for an IIS server.

Comment: Yes, permissions would have to be set correctly, it may not work in a shared hosting environment.  I have this working for files that are outside the webroot on a production server right now without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create page which will take id or image name as get parameter, then load image and writes it to response.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Bitmap test = new Bitmap("fileName.jpg");
test.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```